# Eloquent query is NOT using index

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent query, which (after transpiring to SQL) looks like this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS AGGREGATE
    FROM `tbl_audits`
    WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN '2018-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-10-31 23:59:59' 
    AND `auditable_type` IN ('App\Models\Offer', 'App\Models\AdvertiserContact') 
    AND `fk_user_id` IN ('10250')
```

The table tbl_audits has indexes, however the query is not using it. 
How would you suggest to re-write the query to use indexes?

Just in case I am also attaching my Eloquent query that is generating this SQL query.

```
$logs = Audit::with(array( 'user', 'auditable' ))
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [ "{$start_date} 00:00:00", "{$end_date} 23:59:59" ]);

    if ( $auditLogTypes && $auditLogTypes !== 'null' )
    {
        $auditLogTypesQuery = explode(',', $auditLogTypes);
    }

    if ( in_array(Offer::class, $auditLogTypesQuery) && $offers && $offers !== 'null' )
    {
        $logs->whereIn('auditable_id', explode(',', $offers));
    }

    $logs->whereIn('auditable_type', $auditLogTypesQuery);

    if ( $users && $users !== 'null' )
    {
        $logs->whereIn('fk_user_id', explode(',', $users));
    }

    // count the total data for datatables
    $totalData = $logs->count();

    if ( !$exportToCSV )
    {
        $logs->skip($start)
            ->take($length);
    }

    $logs = $logs->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

Comment: There's no way to rewrite it. Which indexes exist?

Comment: Which indexes exist? What is it meant to use? What does `EXPLAIN` output?

Answer (score 0):

If not exists, you can try to create such a composite index :

```
create index idx_aud_created_userid on tbl_audits (created_at, fk_user_id)
```